# Finding the distribution from the data

Tags: r, distribution

I try to find the distribution for [this dataset](https://copy.com/kWK3NutrTHhAM8Wd). I tried with the `fitdistrplus` package

```
data <- data.matrix(Book1)
descdist(data,  discrete = FALSE)
```

but get this error:

> Error in descdist(data, discrete = FALSE) : data must be a numeric vector

Comment: I used "arena" input analyzer and the results: Distribution: Exponential        Expression: 2.5 + EXPO (3.74) Square Error: 0.000628 Corresponding p-value < 0.005...............Why is so different then "R" results? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use instead

```
data <- as.numeric(Book1)
descdist(data,  discrete = FALSE)
```

This gets you this graph:

[image]

And these values:

```
summary statistics
------
min:  3   max:  35 
median:  5 
mean:  6.244898 
estimated sd:  3.517 
estimated skewness:  1.977063 
estimated kurtosis:  9.456783
```

If you then decide that the closest is an exponentional distribution, you can get its parameters like this

```
ft <- fitdist(data, distr = "exp" )
ft

Fitting of the distribution ' exp ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
      estimate  Std. Error
rate 0.1601307 0.002299016
```

And you can compare their density using this function:

```
denscomp(ft)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: The graph shows where the dataset located in terms of distributions, but how exactly can I find the closest distribution with parameters?

Comment: I used "arena" input analyzer and the results:         Distribution:        Exponential  
             Expression: 2.5 + EXPO (3.74)
             Square Error: 0.000628
             Corresponding p-value < 0.005...............Why is so different then "R" results? Thank you